# What is the difference between qgeom in R and scipy.stats.geom.ppf in Python?

Tags: python, r, scipy, distribution, quantile

My understanding is both ways should give the quantile corresponding to lower tail probability. However, I get different results. 
e.g:- `qgeom(0.99,0.5)` gives 6 in R, wheres `geom.ppf(0.99,0.5)` gives 7 in Python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tldr;** the pmf's of the geometric distribution are different in R and SciPy.

---

1. First off, it's good to confirm that generally quantiles calculated in R and Python agree, for example in the case of the normal distribution

   ```
   from scipy.stats import norm
   norm.ppf(0.99)
   #2.3263478740408408

   qnorm(0.99)
   #[1] 2.326348
   ```
2. For the case of the geometric distribution, the quantile functions differ because the probability mass functions (pmf) are different. In R, the pmf of the geometric distribution is defined as `p(1 - p)^k` (see `help("Geometric")`); in Python's SciPy module the geometric distribution is defined as `p(1 - p)^(k-1)` (see [scipy.stats.geom](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.geom.html#scipy.stats.geom)).

   You can find a summary of key quantities for both definitions in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution). In essence, the `^k` definition is *"used for modeling the number of failures until the first success"*, where as the `^(k-1)` definition relates to *"the probability that the kth trial (out of k trials) is the first success*".

   See also: [Which geometric distribution to use?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11846/which-geometric-distribution-to-use)